# Is there more concise/dynamic way to restrict a type to a set of values as a union type?

Tags: typescript

For an interface property `myProperty` with a predefined set of possible values,
I am using a union type like so:

```
interface MyInterface {
    myProperty: 'foo' | 'bar';
}
```

However, I'm looking for a more concise and dynamic way to define this property that doesn't require manually listing out all possible values.

Using just the primitive type string is not an option since I want to restrict the possible values to only 'foo' and 'bar'.

I want to use it for an Array of objects:

```
[{
   myProperty: 'foo'
},{
   myProperty: 'bar'
}]
```

Is it possible to derive the type from the array?

Comment: If you define the array `as const` you can define it based on the array [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=38&pln=7&pc=15#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBTAggJ1QQwJ4wLwwG0BvAWACgZKYBbLABVRAAdFUosAuGAcgDMQQ3cgF8ANDFIUqtBs1bsu3AEYZUQssIC6MDBBihIUcuXYsa9RkzxwsLELzhI0mLATABXaktaaC3GZbyWNyaxmQAlmBQrLwYwIgwALJYAJJRMXEJklTmsixsnLmWIuRAA)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. 
If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.